# How stop and start some actions in Java? How to pause and continue movement?

Tags: java, keylistener

I am doing an assignment in Java, which is a game. I want to give the user the option to pause the game. What I tried to do was to use KeyListeners. So, at keyPressed the game stops.

Now how do I start the game again with the same button.

This is my code:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
    int key = evt.getKeyCode();
    if ( key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
        dog.setSpeed(0);
        ball.setXspeed(0);
        ball.setYspeed(0);
    }
```

So the object are moving, and when I press Space Bar they all stop. ( which is fine )
But, when I press space again they don't start even though i give them new speed values.

```
if ( key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
    dog.setSpeed(dogSpeed);
    ball.setXspeed(xBallSpeed);
    ball.setYspeed(yBallSpeed);
}
```

Anyone have any idea on how to stop and start some events in Java?

Comment: Why not toggle a boolean value when spacebar is pressed and the animation logic will depend on this boolean value whether or not to do animation?

Comment: Yes you should have a boolean flag which tells you if space bar is hit while game is on (so that you can pause it) or if space bar is hit when game already is paused (so that you can resume it). That will work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both these methods worked.Setting speed to zero and stoping from updating.
However I found another better solution. 
On my program, I have a timer: 

`timer = new Timer(t, new GameMotion());
    timer.start();`

So I just start and stop timer when I press space. You can see the old code commented out. Both way work.

Thank you guys . I appreciate you help .

```
               if (isPlaying == true) {
                    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                        dog.setSpeed(-dogSpeed);
                    }
                    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
                        dog.setSpeed(dogSpeed);
                    }
                    //xBallSpeed = ball.getXballSpeed();
                    //yBallSpeed = ball.getYballSpeed();
                }

                if (key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE ){
                    isPlaying = !isPlaying;
                }

                if (key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE && !isPlaying) {
                    timer.stop();
                    //ball.setXspeed(0);
                    //ball.setYspeed(0);
                }
                else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE && isPlaying ){   
                    //ball.setXspeed(xBallSpeed);
                    //ball.setYspeed(yBallSpeed);
                    timer.start();
                }
```

`

Answer (score 3):

That's not a good solution to your problem. Pausing should stop the game logic from updating, not altering its values to "simulate" a pause state.

What I mean is that you should have something like the following:

```
void updateLogic() {
  if (!isPaused) {
    for (each entity) {
      update position according to speed
    }
  }
}

void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
  int key = evt.getKeyCode();
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
      isPaused = !isPaused;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public boolean isPlaying = true;

if ( key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){

             if(!isPlaying) {
                dog.setSpeed(dogSpeed);
                ball.setXspeed(xBallSpeed);
                ball.setYspeed(yBallSpeed);
                isPlaying = true;
            }
            else {
                dog.setSpeed(0);
                ball.setXspeed(0);
                ball.setYspeed(0);
                isPlaying = false;
            }
          }
```